# javascript scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want my link to scroll down the page to the target content.

This is my script (inside the head tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
            event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And these are my links (inside the body tag):

```
<%= link_to 'Plataformas', root_path + '#plataformas', class: "scroll" %>
<%= link_to 'Contato', root_path + '#contato', class: "scroll" %>
```

This chunks of code are inside my application.html.erb.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It actually goes to the target content but the animation won't work, I mean, it is not a smooth transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem wasn't in the code above, but actually my application.js was missing the require_tree line so it wouldn't load the other js files. Though the answer below it's not the solution for my problem (and that's why I didn't select it) @yodfz_cn was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check $(this.hash).offset().top value;
console.log($(this.hash).offset().top);
look this!

Comment: this is what I got:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(index):80 (anonymous function)

What exactly is undefined, do have any idea?

Comment: this.hash is undefined,edit this,so,where this.hash from ? or what's hash?